# Calculate sum of columns

Tags: jquery, html, addition, jquery-calculation

I have table in which the columns have two input fields. I want to calculate the sum of the **first** input field of the child rows and add the total corresponding to the first input field of the parent row of the column.

Right now with the code, it does add up correctly but it doesn't set the total in the correct input fields of the parent (that is, in the corresponding input field of the parent row).

Please see [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4TnqY/).

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/R5Cjw/)

Code:

**HTML:**

```
<table>
    <tr class="parent-realtor percent-text">
        <td>
            <h5>Realtor Percent</h5>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" class="percent-total" /> //parent
            <input type="text" onfocus="this.blur()" class="percent-data" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" class="percent-total" /> //parent
            <input type="text" onfocus="this.blur()" class="percent-data" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" class="percent-total" /> //parent
            <input type="text" onfocus="this.blur()" class="percent-data" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" class="percent-total" /> //parent
            <input type="text" onfocus="this.blur()" class="percent-data" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <h6>Contract Amount</h6>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" data-parent="realtor" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" data-parent="realtor" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" data-parent="realtor" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" data-parent="realtor" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="percent-text">
        <td>
            <h6>Buyer's Agent</h6>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" data-parent="realtor" class="percent" /> //child
            <input type="text" data-parent="realtor" class="percent-data r" onfocus="this.blur()" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" data-parent="realtor" class="percent" /> //child
            <input type="text" data-parent="realtor" class="percent-data r" onfocus="this.blur()" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" data-parent="realtor" class="percent" /> //child
            <input type="text" data-parent="realtor" class="percent-data r" onfocus="this.blur()" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" data-parent="realtor" class="percent" /> //child
            <input type="text" data-parent="realtor" class="percent-data r" onfocus="this.blur()" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="percent-text">
        <td>
            <h6>Seller's Agent</h6>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" data-parent="realtor" class="percent" /> //child
            <input type="text" data-parent="realtor" class="percent-data r" onfocus="this.blur()" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" data-parent="realtor" class="percent" /> //child
            <input type="text" data-parent="realtor" class="percent-data r" onfocus="this.blur()" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" data-parent="realtor" class="percent" /> //child
            <input type="text" data-parent="realtor" class="percent-data r" onfocus="this.blur()" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" data-parent="realtor" class="percent" /> //child
            <input type="text" data-parent="realtor" class="percent-data r" onfocus="this.blur()" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$('.percent').on('keyup', function () {
    //calcRealtor();
    var totals = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        parent_name = $(this).data('parent'),
        find_parent_row = $('tr.parent-realtor');
    find_parent_row.nextUntil('[class="parent-realtor"]').find('input[data-parent="realtor"]').each(function () {
        totals[$(this).parent('td').index() / 1 - 1] += +this.value;
    });
    find_parent_row.find('input').each(function (i) {
        this.value = totals[i];
    });

});
```

Comment: I've re-read your question several times and still do not understand which fields are to be summed, and where the totals must be placed. Please refactor your question to increase precision. Please write from perspective of a reader who doesn't understand your industry or what you are doing.

Comment: @gibberish, I have elaborated the question little more in detail. I'm not sure how else to explain. Please see jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4TnqY/

Comment: Perhaps add an example of input and expected output to help us figure out what you are trying to do.

Comment: @dsilver1221, I have updated the fiddle with input and output markings: http://jsfiddle.net/R5Cjw/

Comment: @input are you allowed to alter the HTML ?

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli, yes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assumptions

1. You will have multiple groups like on the example in the same `table` element
2. You can add a class `contract` to the `tr` that holds the contract inputs

Try

```
$('table').on('keyup', '.percent', function(){
               // self holds a reference to the input we entered data
    var self = $(this), 
                  // we then find the containing tr element and then find the corresponding `parent-realtor` row and cache it in realtor variable
        realtor = self.closest('tr').prevAll('.parent-realtor').first(),
                // we cache a reference to the all tr rows that interest us
        group = realtor.nextUntil('.parent-realtor'),
                    // we filter the contract inputs
        contracts = group.filter('.contract').find('input'),
                   // and we filter the input elements that will be added to the contracts
        percents = group.filter('.percent-text');

    // for each contract
    contracts.each(function(idx){  // idx holds the index of the contract input
        // gets its value. the + converts it to an number
        var final = +this.value;
        // for each row of elements to add
        percents.each(function(){
            // find the input element that we are interested
            // meaning the one with the same index as our contract input
            // and get its value
            var extra = +$(this).find('input.percent').eq(idx).val();

            // add it to the total of this contracts
            final += extra;
        });

        // find the input that holds the total (based on index again)
        // and assign the total value we just calculated
        realtor.find('input.percent-total').eq(idx).val(final);
    });
});
```

**Demo at** http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/R5Cjw/2/

---

Instead of setting `onfocus="this.blur()"` you could just set the to `readonly` and be done.

Also you could *name* (***with some unique value***) each of the realtor input fields and give that value to each corresponding input element so you could match them easier.

Comment: Thank you so much! I would like to understand what is happening. Can you explain the code? I am setting the element to `readonly` using jQuery but I'm using `onfocus="this.blur()"` because it prevents the cursor from showing in the input field.

Comment: @input, added some comments.. let me know if it helps.. The general idea is that i am matching inputs based on their index in the `tr` row.

Comment: Great solution Gaby +1

Comment: Thanks once again for your time and effort @GabyakaG.Petrioli. Appreciated. The only thing is that the contract amount does not have to be added. So I removed this line `var final = +this.value;`. While this doesn't add the contract amount to the total output and works as I want, it also displays the total in all the 4 output columns disregarding the index. Why is this happening? Please see jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/CFLaX/

Comment: @input see http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/CFLaX/1/ if you want to alter only the *column* in which you edit the input..